# Simplify if statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I simplify this if statement in JavaScript?

```
    if ((sessionStorage.getItem(EXTERNAL_SEARCH) === 'true') && 
       ((storageKey === KEY1) || (storageKey === KEY2))) {
          sessionStorage.setItem(EXTERNAL_SEARCH, 'false');
          return '';
   }
```

Basically what I need is the following:

```
if(condition1 && (condition2 || condition3)){do something}
```

PS. Someone gave me two minus points for my question. I did my research and wrote the best condition I could but knew there is a way to optimize it and that is why I wrote it. If I could have optimized it myself, I wouldn't have posted it.

Comment: You could move `sessionStorage.getItem(EXTERNAL_SEARCH)` to a variable

Comment: @RameshReddy: How would that make any difference?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I think OP is trying to make the condition shorter and make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this:

```
((storageKey === KEY1) || (storageKey === KEY2))
```

To this:

```
[KEY1, KEY2].includes(storageKey)
```

Comment: Thank you. I used your condition in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is unreadable, you should store these expressions in variables and name them with something meaningful, e.g.:

```
let externalSearchEnabled = sessionStorage.getItem(EXTERNAL_SEARCH) === 'true'
let storageKeyIsValid = ((storageKey === KEY1) || (storageKey === KEY2))

if(externalSearchEnabled && storageKeyIsValid) {
   // do something
}
```

The importance of doing this is to maintain the code more clean and readable, you should improve this answer to fit your project, name the variables with the most meaningful name.

## Extra

I watched some lessons from Uncle Bob these days that blew my mind, for those who don't know who he is, he wrote the "Clean Code" book, search about him, he is a legend!

I will leave [this link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmmYSbUCWJ4x1GO839azG_BBw8rkh-zOj) where he talks about clean code. I'm sure that will be a **game-changer on your programming life**

Comment: Thank you for the link that I will review.